# JPQL JPA access google datastore

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, jpql

My entity class :

```
     public class ACCOUNT implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "USERNAME")
private String Username;

@Column(name = "PASSWORD")
private String Password;

public ACCOUNT(String user,String pass)
{
    this.Username=user;
    this.Password=pass;
}

// geter and setter
```

my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

<persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
    <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <class>com.materialshop.server.Datastore.ACCOUNT</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes/>
    <properties>
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.nontx.atomic" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Now persist account and it was successful

```
ACCOUNT ac=new ACCOUNT("admin","123");
em.persist(ac);
```

I checked

```
     http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
```

and yes ,there is ACOUNT entity with 1 record admin and 123

but when I use JPQL to get all entity , it returned null

```
Query q=new Query("SELECT ac FROM ACCOUNT ac");
List<ACCOUNT> list=q.getResultList();
```

even with

```
 em.find(ACCOUNT.class,"admin");
```

return null too

Did i miss something ? Please help me , very grateful for your help

Comment: afaik getResultList() should return an empty List an not null when there are no results. Probably the null is in the EmtityManager. And as Query is an interface, your code should not even compile

Comment: I believe you need a @Entity annotation?